# Can you downcast a NSIndexPath to NSInterger

Tags: ios, nsindexpath, nsinteger, downcast

I have a AVPlayer class that I'm using in a detail view that takes a indexPath of type Int.

I am getting the indexPath from the table view tableViewDidSelectAtIndexPath before sending it to the detail VC to use.

I tried to just simply downcast the NSIndexPath as! NSInteger before sending it to detail VC to use but it crashes without a crash message. So Im a bit stuck as to how to go about this.

Is it possible to downcast this? How can I get the number out of the NSIndexPath into an Int so I can use it in my class?

Comment: Look at the docs for `NSIndexPath` (the base docs and the `UIKit` category). There are appropriate methods for getting the row, section, item, or other indexes from the `indexPath`. And simply casting is completely wrong.

Comment: NSIndexPath* is a pointer to an object. Casting any pointer to an object including NSIndexPath* to Int will most definitely not give you anything even remotely useful.

Answer (score 0):

`NSIndexPath` is always* a combination of *section* and either *row* (for `UITableView`) or *item* (for `UICollectionView`).

you need to dissolve the section by accessing the single index:

```
id object = [[self dataSource] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

*** EDIT**

Respective the comments: you are right. Multiple indexes are possible with `NSIndexPath`.

If you know you have multiple indexes (what I wouldn't expect in `UITableViewDelegate`) you can iterate the indexes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [indexPath length]; i++) {
    NSUInteger index = [indexPath indexAtPosition:i];
    // use index to access whatever you want
}
```

**EDIT**

*PLEASE* read documentation and headers before you ask the next time. Little hint: <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>click</kbd> `NSIndexPath` will take you to its header file with all possible informations.

Comment: Your opening sentence is only partially true. You can also create an `NSIndexPath` with any number of indexes. I created a tree view and the index paths can have any number of indexes.

Comment: FYI - an alternate way to write that 1st line of code: `id object = self.dataSource[indexPath.row];`.

Comment: Correct. This is the alternative `ObjC` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

**Objective C**

```
NSInteger currentRow = indexPath.row;
```

**Swift**

```
let currentRow = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow().row
```